# Separate every 8th File in Linux

Tags: linux

I have list of 544 files as below:
`plt_metgrid_try.000001.png`     to `plt_metgrid_try.000544.png`

I need to separate every 8th file out of this long list of 544 files.

Eg.

```
list 1::  plt_metgrid_try.000001.png, 
          plt_metgrid_try.000009.png,
          plt_metgrid_try.000017.png

list 2::  plt_metgrid_try.000002.png,
          plt_metgrid_try.000010.png,
          plt_metgrid_try.000018.png
.
.
.
.
.
.
list 8:: plt_metgrid_try.000008.png,
         plt_metgrid_try.000016.png,
         plt_metgrid_try.000024.png
```

Likewise, I need to create 8 lists and separate this long list.

How do I separate them?

Please guide to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that 001.png from list 1 goes to file 1 and 009 from list 1 goes to file 2? a sample of the desired output will help if the below answers don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

One loopless `awk` variant

```
awk '{print $0 > "file_"NR%8+1".lst" }' file
```

And a GNU `sed` alternative

```
for n in {0..7}; do sed -n "$n~8p" file > "$n.lst"; done
```

**Edit**

From the comment below, this may be what is wanted....

```
ls -d -- *.png | awk '{print $0 > "file_"NR%8+1".lst" }'
```

Comment: Sir, I tried  **awk '{print $0 > "plt_metgrid_try.000001_"NR%8+1".png" }' plt_metgrid_try.000001.png ** this.. which generates bunch of 8.png files.. But new generated files are not opening.. this is list of images.. after running this code, separate files generates but not opening..

Comment: So do you mean that you have a directory with 544 `png` files and want to create a set of 8 text files each containing a list of the name of every 8th `png` file? If so then update your question to say this, paste in a sample of the directory listing and your expected output..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one file per line:

```
for n in {0..7} ; do awk "(NR%8)==$n {print}" <BigFile.lst >File-$n.lst ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Given 544 filenames from plt_metgrid_try.000001.png to plt_metgrid_try.000544.png, you could assign the 8 arrays in ksh93, bash, or zsh with brace expansion:

```
list1=(plt_metgrid_try.000{001..544..8})
list2=(plt_metgrid_try.000{002..544..8})
list3=(plt_metgrid_try.000{003..544..8})
list4=(plt_metgrid_try.000{004..544..8})
list5=(plt_metgrid_try.000{005..544..8})
list6=(plt_metgrid_try.000{006..544..8})
list7=(plt_metgrid_try.000{007..544..8})
list8=(plt_metgrid_try.000{008..544..8})
```

Brace expansion is a simple textual expansion, not matching, so the filenames in those lists may or may not exist. The brace expansion here starts at the given number and proceeds through 544, using increments of 8.

Comment: Sir, I am new to coding.. Pls guide:: I open the directory where all these 544 images are: and typed it as it is as command **list1=(plt_metgrid_try.000{001..544..8})**.. it wont gave output or error either.. how do I execute it ?

Comment: You said "I need to create 8 lists and separate this long list." so I thought an array of those names was a good way to separate them. You now have a shell variable with those filenames. You could loop over it or expand them all as arguments to another command.